# Shortest hex2bin in ruby?

Tags: ruby, binary, hex

Whats the shortest way to convert hex string to binary string in ruby? for example:

```
class
  def hex2bin

  end
end

"AB12345678".hex2bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def hex2bin
  [self].pack "H*"
end
```

Just found out the pack() function, I think this also works!

Answer (score 3):

```
class String
  def hex2bin
    scan(/../).map { |x| x.to_i(16).chr }.join
  end
end

"AB12345678".hex2bin #=> "\xAB\x124Vx"
```

Comment: you can also do `chars.each_slice(2).map { |x| x.join.to_i(16).chr }.join` which is a bit longer, but likely more efficient because it does not use a regex to extract the char pairs.