# What is the algorithm to compute the Amazon-S3 Etag for a file larger than 5GB?

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

Files uploaded to Amazon S3 that are smaller than 5GB have an ETag that is simply the MD5 hash of the file, which makes it easy to check if your local files are the same as what you put on S3.

But if your file is larger than 5GB, then Amazon computes the ETag differently.

For example, I did a multipart upload of a 5,970,150,664 byte file in 380 parts. Now S3 shows it to have an ETag of `6bcf86bed8807b8e78f0fc6e0a53079d-380`. My local file has an md5 hash of `702242d3703818ddefe6bf7da2bed757`. I think the number after the dash is the number of parts in the multipart upload.

I also suspect that the new ETag (before the dash) is still an MD5 hash, but with some meta data included along the way from the multipart upload somehow.

Does anyone know how to compute the ETag using the same algorithm as Amazon S3?

Comment: Just to clarify, the issue isn't that the ETag algorithm somehow changes if the file is over 5GB. The ETag algorithm is different for non-multipart uploads and for multipart uploads. You'd run into the same problem trying to calculate the ETag of a 6MB file if it were uploaded using one 5MB part and one 1MB part. MD5 is used for non-multipart uploads, which are capped at 5GB. The algorithm in my answer is used for multipart uploads, which are capped at 5GB per part.

Comment: It is also different if you have server side encryption enabled.  I think etag should probably be considered implementation detail, and not be relied upon client-side.

Comment: @wim Any idea how to calculate the ETag when SSE is enabled?

Comment: No. And I don't expect this will even be possible - being able to infer *anything* about the content from the etag itself would run contrary to the goal of encryption in the first place, and if known payload would predictably reproduce the same etag then this would be an information leak.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Say you uploaded a 14MB file to a bucket without server-side encryption, and your part size is 5MB. Calculate 3 MD5 checksums corresponding to each part, i.e. the checksum of the first 5MB, the second 5MB, and the last 4MB. Then take the checksum of their concatenation. MD5 checksums are often printed as hex representations of binary data, so make sure you take the MD5 of the decoded binary concatenation, not of the ASCII or UTF-8 encoded concatenation. When that's done, add a hyphen and the number of parts to get the ETag.

Here are the commands to do it on Mac OS X from the console:

```
$ dd bs=1m count=5 skip=0 if=someFile | md5 >>checksums.txt
5+0 records in
5+0 records out
5242880 bytes transferred in 0.019611 secs (267345449 bytes/sec)
$ dd bs=1m count=5 skip=5 if=someFile | md5 >>checksums.txt
5+0 records in
5+0 records out
5242880 bytes transferred in 0.019182 secs (273323380 bytes/sec)
$ dd bs=1m count=5 skip=10 if=someFile | md5 >>checksums.txt
2+1 records in
2+1 records out
2599812 bytes transferred in 0.011112 secs (233964895 bytes/sec)
```

At this point all the checksums are in `checksums.txt`. To concatenate them and decode the hex and get the MD5 checksum of the lot, just use

```
$ xxd -r -p checksums.txt | md5
```

And now append "-3" to get the ETag, since there were 3 parts.

**Notes**

- If you uploaded with [aws-cli](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) via `aws s3 cp` then you most likely have a 8MB chunksize. According to the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html#multipart-chunksize), that is the default.
- If the bucket has server-side encryption (SSE) turned on, the ETag won't be the MD5 checksum (see [the API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html#API_PutObject_Example_11)). But if you're just trying to verify that an uploaded part matches what you sent, you can use the `Content-MD5` header and [S3 will compare it for you](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_UploadPart.html).
- `md5` on macOS just writes out the checksum, but `md5sum` on Linux/brew also outputs the filename. You'll need to strip that, but I'm sure there's some option to only output the checksums. You don't need to worry about whitespace cause `xxd` will ignore it.

**Code Links**

- A Gist I wrote with a [working script for macOS](https://gist.github.com/emersonf/7413337).
- The project at [s3md5](https://github.com/Teachnova/).

Comment: interesting finding, hoping that amazon will not change it since it's undocumented feature

Comment: Good point. According to the HTTP spec, the ETag is completely up to their discretion, the only guarantee is that they can't return the same ETag for a changed resource. I'm guessing there's not much advantage to changing the algorithm though.

Comment: Is there a way to compute the "part size" out of the etag?

Comment: "Compute" no, "guess" maybe. If the ETag ends in "-4", you know that there are four parts, but that last part can have a size as small as 1 byte up to the part size. So dividing the file size by the number of parts gives you an estimate, but when the number of parts is small, e.g. -2, it gets harder to guess. If you have multiple files that were uploaded using the same part size, you could also look for adjacent part counts, e.g. -4 and -5 and narrow down what the part size can be, e.g. 1.9MB at -2 and 2.1MB at -3 means the part size is 2MB plus or minus 100KB.

Comment: Can you help me translate this in python?

Comment: I don't think it would be wise to rely on the internal implementation of AWS as long as they don't expose their hashing algorithm as a contract especialy if it impacts application correctness which is usually the case when you are verifying the integrity of data.

Comment: @iman if they change it, you might get a false negative, which should raise errors in your application and hopefully make your application fail fast. I don't see how you'd get a false positive.

Comment: A python script versions that works out of the box: https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/9e0c4758b6ce111131a23dcb38bbb1eb

Comment: This no longer appears to be working (I've built a C# implementation). I have found that if I get the MD5s for each part, then add the base64 representation of each parts MD5 to the upload requests Content-MD5 header, the parts upload fine. If I then check each parts upload response ETag, against the hex representation of the parts collected MD5, this matches. However, calculating the MD5 of the concatenated hex strings of all parts MD5's, the ETag value from the upload completion response, then doesn't match the calculated one. I'm either generating it wrong, or its just no longer working.

Comment: @user2295457 I hit this too. The problem is that you need to concatenate the binary digests together, not the ASCII hex digests together

Comment: Bash one-liner equivalent to the above commands: `etag() { local chunk=$1 filename=$2; local size=$(wc -c "$filename" | awk '{ print $1 }'); local parts=$(( ($size >> $chunk) + (! ! ($size & ((1 << $chunk)-1))) )); for i in $(seq 1 "$parts"); do dd status=none if="$filename" ibs=$(( 1 << $chunk )) count=1 skip=$(( $i - 1 )) | openssl dgst -md5 -binary; done | md5sum - | awk '{ print "\"" $1 "'"-$parts"'\"" }'; }; etag 23 path/to/file.txt`. Change the path at the end (and maybe `23` if the chunk size isn't 8MiB, aka 2^23 bytes). This does not handle the edge cases @hyperknot's answer handles

Comment: @AustinAdams why not make this a separate answer, with both a formatted version so it's readable with syntax highlighting, and the 1-liner for easy copy/paste? I'm sure people would be happy to have it.

Answer (score 33):

Based on answers here, I wrote a Python implementation which correctly calculates both multi-part and single-part file ETags.

```py
def calculate_s3_etag(file_path, chunk_size=8 * 1024 * 1024):
    md5s = []

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as fp:
        while True:
            data = fp.read(chunk_size)
            if not data:
                break
            md5s.append(hashlib.md5(data))

    if len(md5s) < 1:
        return '"{}"'.format(hashlib.md5().hexdigest())

    if len(md5s) == 1:
        return '"{}"'.format(md5s[0].hexdigest())

    digests = b''.join(m.digest() for m in md5s)
    digests_md5 = hashlib.md5(digests)
    return '"{}-{}"'.format(digests_md5.hexdigest(), len(md5s))
```

The default chunk_size is 8 MB used by the official `aws cli` tool, and it does multipart upload for 2+ chunks. It should work under both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: seems my chunk size was 16MB utilizing official aws cli tool, maybe they updated it?

Comment: This worked for me on a ~20GB file with an 8MB chunk size. I uploaded to s3 with the deep archive storage class, using aws cli 2.1.15.

Comment: Nice!! 200GB confirmed, thanks!! Double upvote if I could.

Comment: Uploading via the browser, my chunk size was exactly `17179870` bytes.

Answer (score 14):

Here's yet another piece in this crazy AWS challenge puzzle.

FWIW, this answer assumes you already have figured out how to calculate the "MD5 of MD5 parts" and can rebuild your AWS Multi-part ETag from all the other answers already provided here.

What this answer addresses is the annoyance of having to "guess" or otherwise "divine" the original upload part size.

We use several different tools for uploading to S3 and they all seem to have different upload part sizes, so "guessing" really wasn't an option.  Also, we have a lot of files that were historically uploaded when part sizes seemed to be different.  Also, the old trick of using an internal server copy to force the creation of an MD5-type ETag also no longer works as AWS has changed their internal server copies to also use multi-part (just with a fairly large part size).

So...
How can you figure out the object's part size?

Well, if you first make a head_object request and detect that the ETag is a multi-part type ETag (includes a '-<partcount>' at the end), then you can make another head_object request, but with an additional part_number attribute of 1 (the first part).  This follow-on head_object request will then return you the content_length of the first part.   Viola...   Now you know the part size that was used and you can use that size to re-create your local ETag which should match the original uploaded S3 ETag created when the object was uploaded.

Additionally, if you wanted to be exact (perhaps some multi-part uploads were to use variable part sizes), then you could continue to call head_object requests with each part_number specified and calculate each part's MD5 from the returned parts content_length.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Note: I recently had to update my code to follow my own advice in the last paragraph.  We encountered an object with multiple different part sizes!   Go figure!

Answer (score 12):

[bash implementation](https://github.com/antespi/s3md5)

[python implementation](https://github.com/tlastowka/calculate_multipart_etag)

The algorithm literally is (copied from the readme in the python implementation) :

1. md5 the chunks
2. glob the md5 strings together
3. convert the glob to binary
4. md5 the binary of the globbed chunk md5s
5. append "-Number_of_chunks" to the end of the md5 string of the binary

Comment: This does not really explain how the algorithm works, etc. (didn't -1 btw)

Comment: I added the actual algorithm in a step by step list.  I wrote the python implementation wading through posts on how to do it all day, most of them full of incorrect or outdated information.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. Using the default chunk size of 8 (MB) I got a different etag from what amazon tells me is correct.

Comment: @Cory I cannot speak for the bash script, but the python implementation had a problem with file sizes smaller than the chunk size of 8MB. However there is a pull request correcting that problem.

Comment: Took me forever but the python version of this worked for me, with the chunk size of 16 (MB), which I presume may be the new default chunk size

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if it can help:

We're currently doing an ugly (but so far useful) hack to *fix* those *wrong ETags* in multipart uploaded files, which consists on applying a change to the file in the bucket; that triggers a md5 recalculation from Amazon that changes the ETag to matches with the actual md5 signature.

In our case:

File: bucket/Foo.mpg.gpg

1. ETag obtained: "3f92dffef0a11d175e60fb8b958b4e6e-2"
2. Do *something* with the file (*rename it*, add a meta-data like a fake header, among others)
3. Etag obtained: "c1d903ca1bb6dc68778ef21e74cc15b0"

We don't know the algorithm, but since we can "fix" the ETag we don't need to worry about it either.

Comment: It does not work on file larger than 5GB though :( Do you have a workaround for that?

Comment: Seems like this has stopped working, at least for the file I'm checking.

Comment: I have discovered this trick as well trying to understand why the Etags of files uploaded through the web interface were suddenly not computed the expected way. And in 2019, this is still working and doing the trick. Any idea why this is happening and still the case?

Comment: Anyway, it does not seem a good idea to rely on Etag to compare files (beyond that it is long to compute) as the algorithm isn't documented, it gets broken from time to time. Actually,

S3 system metadata seems to contain the file MD5 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata) which maybe would answer the original question. But I haven't tested to retrieve this metadata yet.

Answer (score 10):

Same algorithm, java version:
(BaseEncoding, Hasher, Hashing, etc comes from the [guava library](https://github.com/google/guava)

```java
/**
 * Generate checksum for object came from multipart upload</p>
 * </p>
 * AWS S3 spec: Entity tag that identifies the newly created object's data. Objects with different object data will have different entity tags. The entity tag is an opaque string. The entity tag may or may not be an MD5 digest of the object data. If the entity tag is not an MD5 digest of the object data, it will contain one or more nonhexadecimal characters and/or will consist of less than 32 or more than 32 hexadecimal digits.</p> 
 * Algorithm follows AWS S3 implementation: https://github.com/Teachnova/s3md5</p>
 */
private static String calculateChecksumForMultipartUpload(List<String> md5s) {      
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String md5:md5s) {
        stringBuilder.append(md5);
    }

    String hex = stringBuilder.toString();
    byte raw[] = BaseEncoding.base16().decode(hex.toUpperCase());
    Hasher hasher = Hashing.md5().newHasher();
    hasher.putBytes(raw);
    String digest = hasher.hash().toString();

    return digest + "-" + md5s.size();
}
```

Comment: My freaking hero!!!!!!!!! I spend many MANY hours trying to get the binary encoding correct... I didnt know guava had this functionality.

Comment: Very nice, works like a charm. Just a note: you can use the oneliner `DigestUtils.md5Hex(raw)` from `apache-commons` instead of Guava Hasher if needed.

Comment: @Pom12 Can you please convert this function in typescript?

Answer (score 7):

According to the AWS documentation the ETag isn't an MD5 hash for a multi-part upload nor for an encrypted object: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html

> Objects created by the PUT Object, POST Object, or Copy operation, or through the AWS Management Console, and are encrypted by SSE-S3 or plaintext, have ETags that are an MD5 digest of their object data.
>
> Objects created by the PUT Object, POST Object, or Copy operation, or through the AWS Management Console, and are encrypted by SSE-C or SSE-KMS, have ETags that are not an MD5 digest of their object data.
>
> If an object is created by either the Multipart Upload or Part Copy operation, the ETag is not an MD5 digest, regardless of the method of encryption.

Answer (score 5):

In an above answer, someone asked if there was a way to get the md5 for files larger than 5G.

An answer that I could give for getting the MD5 value (for files larger than 5G) would be to either add it manually to the metadata, or use a program to do your uploads which will add the information.

For example, I used s3cmd to upload a file, and it added the following metadata.

```
$ aws s3api head-object --bucket xxxxxxx --key noarch/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm 
{
  "AcceptRanges": "bytes", 
  "ContentType": "binary/octet-stream", 
  "LastModified": "Sat, 19 Sep 2015 03:27:25 GMT", 
  "ContentLength": 14540, 
  "ETag": "\"2cd0ae668a585a14e07c2ea4f264d79b\"", 
  "Metadata": {
    "s3cmd-attrs": "uid:502/gname:staff/uname:xxxxxx/gid:20/mode:33188/mtime:1352129496/atime:1441758431/md5:2cd0ae668a585a14e07c2ea4f264d79b/ctime:1441385182"
  }
}
```

It isn't a direct solution using the ETag, but it is a way to populate the metadata you want (MD5) in a way you can access it.  It will still fail if someone uploads the file without metadata.

Answer (score 5):

node.js implementation -

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const chunk = 1024 * 1024 * 5; // 5MB

const md5 = data => crypto.createHash('md5').update(data).digest('hex');

const getEtagOfFile = (filePath) => {
  const stream = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  if (stream.length <= chunk) {
    return md5(stream);
  }
  const md5Chunks = [];
  const chunksNumber = Math.ceil(stream.length / chunk);
  for (let i = 0; i < chunksNumber; i++) {
    const chunkStream = stream.slice(i * chunk, (i + 1) * chunk);
    md5Chunks.push(md5(chunkStream));
  }

  return `${md5(Buffer.from(md5Chunks.join(''), 'hex'))}-${chunksNumber}`;
};
```

Comment: This algorithm does not behave exactly the way S3 does when the file size is exactly of the size of one chunk. This may depend on how the upload was done by the tool though.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out @bernardn - I just got an issue for my library, is it possible AWS recently changed this? https://github.com/pyramation/etag-hash/issues/1

Comment: if AWS recently changed, I believe this solution would now be correct for 1 chunk, and maybe before was incorrect. However, I'm trying to do due diligence before updating the library to ensure it's officially changed.

Comment: @pyramation I retested my tool [here](https://github.com/bn3t/calculate-etag) and I don't think there are any change to AWS implementation as my tests are still successful. What could have change is the way files are uploaded either by the web interface or by aws-cli.

Comment: i took a different approach which seems to match the original bash implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70375683/492325

Answer (score 3):

Here is the algorithm in ruby...

```rb
require 'digest'

# PART_SIZE should match the chosen part size of the multipart upload
# Set here as 10MB
PART_SIZE = 1024*1024*10 

class File
  def each_part(part_size = PART_SIZE)
    yield read(part_size) until eof?
  end
end

file = File.new('<path_to_file>')

hashes = []

file.each_part do |part|
  hashes << Digest::MD5.hexdigest(part)
end

multipart_hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest([hashes.join].pack('H*'))
multipart_etag = "#{multipart_hash}-#{hashes.count}"
```

Thanks to [Shortest Hex2Bin in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244414/shortest-hex2bin-in-ruby) and [Multipart Uploads to S3 ...](https://itsecureadmin.com/2015/11/multipart-uploads-to-s3-using-aws-sdk-v2-for-ruby/)

Comment: Nice! I confirm this works for me. Minor change: the last "multi_part_hash" should be "multipart_hash". I also added an "ARGV.each do" loop around the main part and a print at the end to make it a command-line script.

Answer (score 2):

And here is a PHP version of calculating the ETag:

```php
function calculate_aws_etag($filename, $chunksize) {
    /*
    DESCRIPTION:
    - calculate Amazon AWS ETag used on the S3 service
    INPUT:
    - $filename : path to file to check
    - $chunksize : chunk size in Megabytes
    OUTPUT:
    - ETag (string)
    */
    $chunkbytes = $chunksize*1024*1024;
    if (filesize($filename) < $chunkbytes) {
        return md5_file($filename);
    } else {
        $md5s = array();
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
        if ($handle === false) {
            return false;
        }
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $buffer = fread($handle, $chunkbytes);
            $md5s[] = md5($buffer);
            unset($buffer);
        }
        fclose($handle);

        $concat = '';
        foreach ($md5s as $indx => $md5) {
            $concat .= hex2bin($md5);
        }
        return md5($concat) .'-'. count($md5s);
    }
}

$etag = calculate_aws_etag('path/to/myfile.ext', 8);
```

And here is an enhanced version that can verify against an expected ETag - and even guess the chunksize if you don't know it!

```php
function calculate_etag($filename, $chunksize, $expected = false) {
    /*
    DESCRIPTION:
    - calculate Amazon AWS ETag used on the S3 service
    INPUT:
    - $filename : path to file to check
    - $chunksize : chunk size in Megabytes
    - $expected : verify calculated etag against this specified etag and return true or false instead
        - if you make chunksize negative (eg. -8 instead of 8) the function will guess the chunksize by checking all possible sizes given the number of parts mentioned in $expected
    OUTPUT:
    - ETag (string)
    - or boolean true|false if $expected is set
    */
    if ($chunksize < 0) {
        $do_guess = true;
        $chunksize = 0 - $chunksize;
    } else {
        $do_guess = false;
    }

    $chunkbytes = $chunksize*1024*1024;
    $filesize = filesize($filename);
    if ($filesize < $chunkbytes && (!$expected || !preg_match("/^\\w{32}-\\w+$/", $expected))) {
        $return = md5_file($filename);
        if ($expected) {
            $expected = strtolower($expected);
            return ($expected === $return ? true : false);
        } else {
            return $return;
        }
    } else {
        $md5s = array();
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
        if ($handle === false) {
            return false;
        }
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $buffer = fread($handle, $chunkbytes);
            $md5s[] = md5($buffer);
            unset($buffer);
        }
        fclose($handle);

        $concat = '';
        foreach ($md5s as $indx => $md5) {
            $concat .= hex2bin($md5);
        }
        $return = md5($concat) .'-'. count($md5s);
        if ($expected) {
            $expected = strtolower($expected);
            $matches = ($expected === $return ? true : false);
            if ($matches || $do_guess == false || strlen($expected) == 32) {
                return $matches;
            } else {
                // Guess the chunk size
                preg_match("/-(\\d+)$/", $expected, $match);
                $parts = $match[1];
                $min_chunk = ceil($filesize / $parts /1024/1024);
                $max_chunk =  floor($filesize / ($parts-1) /1024/1024);
                $found_match = false;
                for ($i = $min_chunk; $i <= $max_chunk; $i++) {
                    if (calculate_aws_etag($filename, $i) === $expected) {
                        $found_match = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return $found_match;
            }
        } else {
            return $return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you take the 128bit binary md5 digest of each part, concatenate them into a document, and hash that document. The algorithm presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19896823/5556676) is accurate.

**Note:** the multipart ETAG form with the hyphen will change to the form without the hyphen if you "touch" the blob (even without modifying the content). That is, if you copy, or do an in-place copy of your completed multipart-uploaded object (aka PUT-COPY), S3 will recompute the ETAG with the simple version of the algorithm. i.e. the destination object will have an etag without the hyphen.

You've probably considered this already, but if your files are less than 5GB, and you already know their MD5s, and upload parallelization provides little to no benefit (e.g. you are streaming the upload from a slow network, or uploading from a slow disk), then you may also consider using a simple PUT instead of a multipart PUT, and pass your known Content-MD5 in your request headers -- amazon will fail the upload if they don't match. Keep in mind that you get charged for each UploadPart.

Furthermore, in some clients, passing a known MD5 for the input of a PUT operation will save the client from recomputing the MD5 during the transfer. In boto3 (python), you would use the `ContentMD5` parameter of the [client.put_object()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) method, for instance. If you omit the parameter, and you already knew the MD5, then the client would be wasting cycles computing it again before the transfer.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding chunk size, I noticed that it seems to depend of number of parts.
The maximun number of parts are 10000 as AWS documents.

So starting on a default of 8MB and knowing the filesize, chunk size and parts can be calculated as follows:

```
chunk_size=8*1024*1024
flsz=os.path.getsize(fl)

while flsz/chunk_size>10000:
  chunk_size*=2

parts=math.ceil(flsz/chunk_size)
```

Parts have to be up-rounded

Answer (score 2):

Working algorithm implemented in Node.js (TypeScript).

```js
/**
 * Generate an S3 ETAG for multipart uploads in Node.js 
 * An implementation of this algorithm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19896823/492325
 * Author: Richard Willis <willis.rh@gmail.com>
 */
import fs from 'node:fs';
import crypto, { BinaryLike } from 'node:crypto';

const defaultPartSizeInBytes = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB

function md5(contents: string | BinaryLike): string {
  return crypto.createHash('md5').update(contents).digest('hex');
}

export function getS3Etag(
  filePath: string,
  partSizeInBytes = defaultPartSizeInBytes
): string {
  const { size: fileSizeInBytes } = fs.statSync(filePath);
  let parts = Math.floor(fileSizeInBytes / partSizeInBytes);
  if (fileSizeInBytes % partSizeInBytes > 0) {
    parts += 1;
  }
  const fileDescriptor = fs.openSync(filePath, 'r');
  let totalMd5 = '';

  for (let part = 0; part < parts; part++) {
    const skipBytes = partSizeInBytes * part;
    const totalBytesLeft = fileSizeInBytes - skipBytes;
    const bytesToRead = Math.min(totalBytesLeft, partSizeInBytes);
    const buffer = Buffer.alloc(bytesToRead);
    fs.readSync(fileDescriptor, buffer, 0, bytesToRead, skipBytes);
    totalMd5 += md5(buffer);
  }

  const combinedHash = md5(Buffer.from(totalMd5, 'hex'));
  const etag = `${combinedHash}-${parts}`;
  return etag;
}
```

I've published this to npm

```
npm install s3-etag
```

```js
import { generateETag } from 's3-etag';

const etag = generateETag(absoluteFilePath, partSizeInBytes);
```

View project here: https://github.com/badsyntax/s3-etag

Answer (score 1):

A version in Rust:

```rust
use crypto::digest::Digest;
use crypto::md5::Md5;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::iter::repeat;

fn calculate_etag_from_read(f: &mut dyn Read, chunk_size: usize) -> Result<String> {
    let mut md5 = Md5::new();
    let mut concat_md5 = Md5::new();
    let mut input_buffer = vec![0u8; chunk_size];
    let mut chunk_count = 0;
    let mut current_md5: Vec<u8> = repeat(0).take((md5.output_bits() + 7) / 8).collect();

    let md5_result = loop {
        let amount_read = f.read(&mut input_buffer)?;
        if amount_read > 0 {
            md5.reset();
            md5.input(&input_buffer[0..amount_read]);
            chunk_count += 1;
            md5.result(&mut current_md5);
            concat_md5.input(&current_md5);
        } else {
            if chunk_count > 1 {
                break format!("{}-{}", concat_md5.result_str(), chunk_count);
            } else {
                break md5.result_str();
            }
        }
    };
    Ok(md5_result)
}

fn calculate_etag(file: &String, chunk_size: usize) -> Result<String> {
    let mut f = File::open(file)?;
    calculate_etag_from_read(&mut f, chunk_size)
}
```

See a repo with a simple implementation: https://github.com/bn3t/calculate-etag/tree/master

Answer (score 1):

Extending [Timothy Gonzalez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43817101/8896457):

Identical files will have different etag when using multipart upload.

It's easy to test it with WinSCP, because it uses multipart upload.

When I upload multiple indentical copies of the same file to S3 via WinSCP then each has different etag. When I download them and calculate md5, then they are still indentical.

So from what I tested different etags doesn't mean that files are different.

I see no alternative way to obtain any hash for S3 files without downloading them first.

This is true for multipart uploads. For not-multipart it should still be possible to calculate etag locally.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for iOS and macOS without using external helpers like dd and xxd. I have just found it, so I report it as it is, planning to improve it at a later stage. For the moment, it relies on both Objective-C and Swift code. First of all, create this helper class in Objective-C:

**AWS3MD5Hash.h**

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface AWS3MD5Hash : NSObject

- (NSData *)dataFromFile:(FILE *)theFile startingOnByte:(UInt64)startByte length:(UInt64)length filePath:(NSString *)path singlePartSize:(NSUInteger)partSizeInMb;

- (NSData *)dataFromBigData:(NSData *)theData startingOnByte:(UInt64)startByte length:(UInt64)length;

- (NSData *)dataFromHexString:(NSString *)sourceString;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**AWS3MD5Hash.m**

```c
#import "AWS3MD5Hash.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 256

@implementation AWS3MD5Hash


- (NSData *)dataFromFile:(FILE *)theFile startingOnByte:(UInt64)startByte length:(UInt64)length filePath:(NSString *)path singlePartSize:(NSUInteger)partSizeInMb {


   char *buffer = malloc(length);


   NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
   NSNumber *fileSizeValue = nil;
   NSError *fileSizeError = nil;
   [fileURL getResourceValue:&fileSizeValue
                           forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey
                            error:&fileSizeError];

   NSInteger __unused result = fseek(theFile,startByte,SEEK_SET);

   if (result != 0) {
      free(buffer);
      return nil;
   }

   NSInteger result2 = fread(buffer, length, 1, theFile);

   NSUInteger difference = fileSizeValue.integerValue - startByte;

   NSData *toReturn;

   if (result2 == 0) {
       toReturn = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:difference];
    } else {
       toReturn = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:result2 * length];
    }

     free(buffer);

     return toReturn;
 }

 - (NSData *)dataFromBigData:(NSData *)theData startingOnByte:  (UInt64)startByte length:(UInt64)length {

   NSUInteger fileSizeValue = theData.length;
   NSData *subData;

   if (startByte + length > fileSizeValue) {
        subData = [theData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(startByte, fileSizeValue - startByte)];
    } else {
       subData = [theData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(startByte, length)];
    }

        return subData;
    }

- (NSData *)dataFromHexString:(NSString *)string {
    string = [string lowercaseString];
    NSMutableData *data= [NSMutableData new];
    unsigned char whole_byte;
    char byte_chars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'};
    NSInteger i = 0;
    NSInteger length = string.length;
    while (i < length-1) {
       char c = [string characterAtIndex:i++];
       if (c < '0' || (c > '9' && c < 'a') || c > 'f')
           continue;
       byte_chars[0] = c;
       byte_chars[1] = [string characterAtIndex:i++];
       whole_byte = strtol(byte_chars, NULL, 16);
       [data appendBytes:&whole_byte length:1];
    }

        return data;
}


@end
```

Now create a plain swift file:

**AWS Extensions.swift**

```swift
import UIKit
import CommonCrypto

extension URL {

func calculateAWSS3MD5Hash(_ numberOfParts: UInt64) -> String? {


    do {

        var fileSize: UInt64!
        var calculatedPartSize: UInt64!

        let attr:NSDictionary? = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: self.path) as NSDictionary
        if let _attr = attr {
            fileSize = _attr.fileSize();
            if numberOfParts != 0 {



                let partSize = Double(fileSize / numberOfParts)

                var partSizeInMegabytes = Double(partSize / (1024.0 * 1024.0))



                partSizeInMegabytes = ceil(partSizeInMegabytes)

                calculatedPartSize = UInt64(partSizeInMegabytes)

                if calculatedPartSize % 2 != 0 {
                    calculatedPartSize += 1
                }

                if numberOfParts == 2 || numberOfParts == 3 { // Very important when there are 2 or 3 parts, in the majority of times
                                                              // the calculatedPartSize is already 8. In the remaining cases we force it.
                    calculatedPartSize = 8
                }


                if mainLogToggling {
                    print("The calculated part size is \(calculatedPartSize!) Megabytes")
                }

            }

        }

        if numberOfParts == 0 {

            let string = self.memoryFriendlyMd5Hash()
            return string

        }




        let hasher = AWS3MD5Hash.init()
        let file = fopen(self.path, "r")
        defer { let result = fclose(file)}


        var index: UInt64 = 0
        var bigString: String! = ""
        var data: Data!

        while autoreleasepool(invoking: {

                if index == (numberOfParts-1) {
                    if mainLogToggling {
                        //print("Siamo all'ultima linea.")
                    }
                }

                data = hasher.data(from: file!, startingOnByte: index * calculatedPartSize * 1024 * 1024, length: calculatedPartSize * 1024 * 1024, filePath: self.path, singlePartSize: UInt(calculatedPartSize))

                bigString = bigString + MD5.get(data: data) + "\n"

                index += 1

                if index == numberOfParts {
                    return false
                }
                return true

        }) {}

        let final = MD5.get(data :hasher.data(fromHexString: bigString)) + "-\(numberOfParts)"

        return final

    } catch {

    }

    return nil
}

   func memoryFriendlyMd5Hash() -> String? {

    let bufferSize = 1024 * 1024

    do {
        // Open file for reading:
        let file = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: self)
        defer {
            file.closeFile()
        }

        // Create and initialize MD5 context:
        var context = CC_MD5_CTX()
        CC_MD5_Init(&context)

        // Read up to `bufferSize` bytes, until EOF is reached, and update MD5 context:
        while autoreleasepool(invoking: {
            let data = file.readData(ofLength: bufferSize)
            if data.count > 0 {
                data.withUnsafeBytes {
                    _ = CC_MD5_Update(&context, $0, numericCast(data.count))
                }
                return true // Continue
            } else {
                return false // End of file
            }
        }) { }

        // Compute the MD5 digest:
        var digest = Data(count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        digest.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
            _ = CC_MD5_Final($0, &context)
        }
        let hexDigest = digest.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
        return hexDigest

    } catch {
        print("Cannot open file:", error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
}

struct MD5 {

    static func get(data: Data) -> String {
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))

        let _ = data.withUnsafeBytes { bytes in
            CC_MD5(bytes, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)
        }
        var digestHex = ""
        for index in 0..<Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH) {
            digestHex += String(format: "%02x", digest[index])
        }

        return digestHex
    }
    // The following is a memory friendly version
    static func get2(data: Data) -> String {

    var currentIndex = 0
    let bufferSize = 1024 * 1024
    //var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))

    // Create and initialize MD5 context:
    var context = CC_MD5_CTX()
    CC_MD5_Init(&context)


    while autoreleasepool(invoking: {
        var subData: Data!
        if (currentIndex + bufferSize) < data.count {
            subData = data.subdata(in: Range.init(NSMakeRange(currentIndex, bufferSize))!)
            currentIndex = currentIndex + bufferSize
        } else {
            subData = data.subdata(in: Range.init(NSMakeRange(currentIndex, data.count - currentIndex))!)
            currentIndex = currentIndex + (data.count - currentIndex)
        }
        if subData.count > 0 {
            subData.withUnsafeBytes {
                _ = CC_MD5_Update(&context, $0, numericCast(subData.count))
            }
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }

    }) { }

    // Compute the MD5 digest:
    var digest = Data(count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    digest.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
        _ = CC_MD5_Final($0, &context)
    }

    var digestHex = ""
    for index in 0..<Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH) {
        digestHex += String(format: "%02x", digest[index])
    }

    return digestHex

}
}
```

Now add:

```c
#import "AWS3MD5Hash.h"
```

to your Objective-C Bridging header. You should be ok with this setup.

**Example usage**

To test this setup, you could be calling the following method inside the object that is in charge of handling the AWS connections:

```swift
func getMd5HashForFile() {


    let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: AWSRegionType.USEast2, identityPoolId: "<INSERT_POOL_ID>")
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.APSoutheast2, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
    configuration?.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 3.0
    configuration?.timeoutIntervalForResource = 3.0

    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    AWSS3.register(with: configuration!, forKey: "defaultKey")
    let s3 = AWSS3.s3(forKey: "defaultKey")


    let headObjectRequest = AWSS3HeadObjectRequest()!
    headObjectRequest.bucket = "<NAME_OF_YOUR_BUCKET>"
    headObjectRequest.key = self.latestMapOnServer.key




    let _: AWSTask? = s3.headObject(headObjectRequest).continueOnSuccessWith { (awstask) -> Any? in

        let headObjectOutput: AWSS3HeadObjectOutput? = awstask.result

        var ETag = headObjectOutput?.eTag!
        // Here you should parse the returned Etag and extract the number of parts to provide to the helper function. Etags end with a "-" followed by the number of parts. If you don't see this format, then pass 0 as the number of parts.
        ETag = ETag!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")

        print("headObjectOutput.ETag \(ETag!)")

        let mapOnDiskUrl = self.getMapsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(self.latestMapOnDisk!)

        let hash = mapOnDiskUrl.calculateAWSS3MD5Hash(<Take the number of parts from the ETag returned by the server>)

        if hash == ETag {
            print("They are the same.")
        }

        print ("\(hash!)")

        return nil
    }



}
```

If the ETag returned by the server does not have "-" at the end of the ETag, just pass 0 to calculateAWSS3MD5Hash. Please comment if you encounter any problems. I am working on a swift only solution, I will update this answer as soon as I finish. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that the AWS S3 Console 'upload' uses an unusual part (chunk) size of 17,179,870 - at least for larger files.

Using that part size gave me the correct ETag hash using the methods described earlier.  Thanks to @TheStoryCoder for the php version.

Thanks to @hans for his idea to use head-object to see the actual sizes of each part.

I used the AWS S3 Console (on Nov28 2020) to upload about 50 files ranging in size from 190MB to 2.3GB and all of them had the same part size of 17,179,870.

Answer (score 0):

I liked Emerson's leading answer above - especially the `xxd` part - but I was too lazy to use `dd` so I went with `split`, guessing at an 8M chunk size because I uploaded with `aws s3 cp`:

```
$ split -b 8M large.iso XXX
$ md5sum XXX* > checksums.txt
$ sed -i 's/ .*$//' checksums.txt 
$ xxd -r -p checksums.txt | md5sum
99a090df013d375783f0f0be89288529  -
$ wc -l checksums.txt 
80 checksums.txt
$
```

It was immediately obvious that both parts of my S3 etag matched my file's calculated etag.

UPDATE:

This has been working nicely:

```
$ ll large.iso
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user   user   669134848 Apr 12  2021 large.iso
$ 
$ etag large.iso
99a090df013d375783f0f0be89288529-80
$ 
$ type etag
etag is a function
etag () 
{ 
    split -b 8M --filter=md5sum $1 | cut -d' ' -f1 | pee "xxd -r -p | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1" "wc -l" | paste -d'-' - -
}
$
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers assume a standard and regular part size. But that assumption may not be true. Across the console and various SDKs there are different defaults. And the low-level API does allow a lot of variety.

Complications:

- S3 multi-part uploads can have parts of any size (within a min and max for non-last parts).
- Even the non-last parts can be different sizes.
- When you upload they don't have to be consecutive part numbers.
- If you do a multi-part upload with only 1 part, the etag is the more complicated version, not the simple MD5
- etags tend to be wrapped in double-quotes. I don't know why. But that's just a thing that might trip you up.

So we need find find out how many parts there are, and how big they are.

- You cannot reliably get the part count from [boto3's `Object.parts_count`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.parts_count) attribute. I don't know if the same is true of other SDKs.
- The [`get_object_attributes` API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object_attributes) documentation claims that it returns a list of parts and sizes. But when I tested those fields were missing. Even for multi-part uploads that were not completed.
- Even if you assume equal part sizes (except the last part), you cannot deduce part size from content length and part count. e.g. if a 90MB file has 3 parts, was that 30MBx3, or 40MB+40MB+10MB?

Let's assume that you have a local file and you want to check whether it matches the content of the object in S3.
(And assume that you've already checked whether the lengths differ, because that's a faster check.)

Here's a python3 script to do that. (I chose python just because that's what I'm familiar with.)

We use `head_object` to get the e-tag. With the e-tag we can deduce whether it was a single-part upload or multi-part, and how many parts.
We use `head_object` passing in `PartNumber`, calling that for each part, to get the length of each part. You could use multiprocessing to speed that up. (Noting that `boto3`'s `client` should not be passed between processes.)

```
import boto3
from hashlib import md5

def content_matches(local_path, bucket, key) -> bool:
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    resp = client.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    remote_e_tag = resp['ETag']
    total_length = resp['ContentLength']
    if '-' not in remote_e_tag:
        # it was a single-part upload
        m = md5()
        
        # you could read from the file in chunks to avoid loading the whole thing into memory
        # the chunks would not have to match any SDK standard. It can be whatever you want.
        # (The MD5 library will act as if you hashed in one go)
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            local_etag = f'"md5(f.read()).hexdigest()"'
        return local_etag == remote_e_tag
    else:
        # multi-part upload
        # to find the number of parts, get it from the e-tag
        # e.g. 123-56 has 56 parts
        num_parts = int(remote_e_tag.strip('"').split('-')[-1])
        print(f"Assuming {num_parts=} from {remote_e_tag=}")
        
        md5s = []
    
        with open(local_path, 'rb') as f:
            sz_read = 0
            
            for part_num in range(1,num_parts+1):
                resp = client.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, PartNumber=part_num)
                
                sz_read += resp['ContentLength']
                local_data_part = f.read(resp['ContentLength'])
                assert len(local_data_part) == resp['ContentLength'] # sanity check
                md5s.append(md5(local_data_part))
        assert sz_read == total_length, "Sum of part sizes doesn't equal total file size"
        digests = b''.join(m.digest() for m in md5s)
        digests_md5 = md5(digests)
        local_etag = f'"{digests_md5.hexdigest()}-{len(md5s)}"'
        return remote_e_tag == local_etag
```

And a script to test it with all those edge cases:

```
import boto3
from pprint import pprint
from hashlib import md5
from main import content_matches

MB = 2 ** 20

bucket = 'mybucket'
key = 'test-multi-part-upload'
local_path = 'test-data'

# first upload the object
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
mpu = obj.initiate_multipart_upload()

parts = []
part_sizes = [6 * MB, 5 * MB, 5] # deliberately non-standard and not consistent
upload_part_nums = [1,3,8] # test non-consecutive part numbers for upload
with open(local_path, 'wb') as fw:
    with open('/dev/random', 'rb') as fr:
        for (part_num, part_size) in zip(upload_part_nums, part_sizes):
            part = mpu.Part(part_num)
            data = fr.read(part_size)
            print(f"Uploading part {part_num}")
            resp = part.upload(Body=data)
            parts.append({
                'ETag': resp['ETag'],
                'PartNumber': part_num
            })
            fw.write(data)

resp = mpu.complete(MultipartUpload={
    'Parts': parts
})

obj.reload()

assert content_matches(local_path, bucket, key)
```

Answer (score 0):

"@wim Any idea how to calculate the ETag when SSE is enabled?"
in my testing, multipart+SEE-C, the Etag is valid.
can be calculated from the individual Etag returned for each part.
and this is easy to prove.
let's say we have a multipart upload with SEE-C, with 10 parts.

take the 10 Etags, put them in a file, and run "xxd -r -p checksums.txt | md5sum", the calculdated value with match the value returned from aws
etag parts

```
-------------------------------
1330e1275b556ab6702bca9438f62c15  -
ae55d3ddf52e33d45140a5be6dacb925  -
16dc956e05962b84ad9cd74a05e86797  -
64be66992a5110c4b1151a8249258a1a  -
4926df0200fe24499524176d6a85e347  -
2b6655c3506481eb1fae6b2e2e7c4b8b  -
a02e9dbd49039eaf4d6de1fddc5e1a30  -
afb7bc1f6e0c1f23671cb7116f3b0c63  -
dddf3a1ab192f26bb483a3e2778bab13  -
adb8b2b761640418856853f3810ac45a  -
-------------------------------

etag_from_aws   = c68db040f8a36c164259bcca40c36410-10

etag_calculated = c68db040f8a36c164259bcca40c36410-10
```

Answer (score -4):

No,

Till now there is not solution to match normal file ETag and Multipart file ETag and MD5 of local file.