# Amazon S3 multipart upload ETag generation method

Tags: amazon-s3

**EDIT**: [Emerson Farrugia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/614482/emerson-farrugia)  answered this at: [What is the algorithm to compute the Amazon-S3 Etag for a file larger than 5GB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186993/what-is-the-algorithm-to-compute-the-amazon-s3-etag-for-a-file-larger-than-5gb/19896823#19896823)

As you may already know, when one uploads large files using the amazon multipart upload API:

```
Initiate Multipart Upload -> Upload Part 1, Upload Part2 ... Upload Part n -> Complete Multipart Upload
```

"Complete Multipart Upload" will return an ETag with the following format:

```
multiparthash-number
```

where the number is the **number** of parts uploaded with "Upload Part".

Now my question is how this **multiparthash** is calculated. I find something in a blog stating that:

```
multiparthash = md5(L1:H1:L2:H2…:Ln:Hn:)
```

where Ln is the index and Hn is the ETAg of part n. But this, for me at least, is not working.

Is there any official documentation on this or any know-how?

Comment: I just answered this on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186993/what-is-the-algorithm-to-compute-the-amazon-s3-etag-for-a-file-larger-than-5gb/19896823#19896823