# How does the IfMatch argument for the AWS boto3 get_object call work?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, etag

The [boto3 s3 `get_object`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) function
documentation (which is autogenerated from AWS service definition files) describes the `IfMatch` argument as

> Return the object only if its entity tag (ETag) is the same as the one specified, otherwise return a 412 (precondition failed).

However when I try to use the `IfMatch` argument I'm unable to get S3 to respond either with a non-200 HTTP status code or by throwing an exception.

This example code

```py
import boto3
import hashlib
import json

BUCKET = 'your-bucket-name-goes-here'
data = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'buz'}
payload = json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4).encode('UTF-8')
etag = hashlib.md5(payload).hexdigest()
print("Locally computed etag : {}".format(etag))
client = boto3.client('s3')
response = client.put_object(
    Body=payload,
    Bucket=BUCKET,
    ContentType='application/json',
    Key='/test.json')
etag_with_quotes = response['ETag']
print("Etag returned from put_object: {}".format(etag_with_quotes))

response = client.get_object(
  Bucket=BUCKET,
  Key='/test.json',
  IfMatch=etag
)
print("Etag returned from get_object: {}".format(response['ETag']))
print("HTTP status code : {}".format(response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']))

response = client.get_object(
  Bucket=BUCKET,
  Key='/test.json',
  IfMatch=etag_with_quotes
)
print("Etag returned from get_object: {}".format(response['ETag']))
print("HTTP status code : {}".format(response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']))
```

produces this output

```
Locally computed etag : d14e36174d57c305bd9d7c171e669ac8
Etag returned from put_object: "d14e36174d57c305bd9d7c171e669ac8"
Etag returned from get_object: "d14e36174d57c305bd9d7c171e669ac8"
HTTP status code : 200
Etag returned from get_object: "d14e36174d57c305bd9d7c171e669ac8"
HTTP status code : 200
```

How is one supposed to use the `IfMatch` argument to avoid downloading a file if the local copy is the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IfMatch` downloads the object if the ETag matches.  To download only if different, use `IfNoneMatch`.

---

Note also that this only works for objects not uploaded using multipart uploads.  Multpart uploads use a [different ETag algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12186993/1695906) containing a hex md5 hash of the binary (not hex) md5 hashes of the individual parts, then a `-`, and then the number of parts.  You can successfully calculate these yourself, but it's more complicated.

Comment: Excellent. Confirmed that this works. Switching to use `IfNoneMatch` results in a `ClientError: An error occurred (304) when calling the GetObject operation: Not Modified` exception which I can catch and know that the file hasn't changed. Thanks!