# Checking MD5 of files present in an S3 bucket and loading files not already present

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a requirement to load data from our on-prem servers to S3 buckets. A python script will be scheduled to run every morning for loading of any new files that arrive on on-prem servers.

However, loaded files are not removed from our on-prem servers, and I need to load files that have not already been loaded to S3 buckets.

Folder Structure on on-prem servers and S3 buckets need to be exact, like given below:

```
MainFolder/
├── SubFolderOne/
│   ├── File1
│   ├── File2
│   ├── File3
│   └── File4
├── SubFolderTwo/
│   ├── File1
│   └── File2
└── SubFolderThree/
    ├── File1
    ├── File2
    ├── File3
    └── File4
```

where MainFolder is the folder that needs to be monitored. A folder in our s3 bucket exists with the same name. Everything under MainFolder on on-prem servers and in S3 bucket, needs to be exactly the same.

I tried using etag values to compare files, but etag values and md5 hash values is not same, for exactly same file.

Is there any way to implement this requirement?

Comment: Can you clarify why the md5 is required? So files with the same name can change and should be re-uploaded then? Note: the ETag is, if it carries a md5, also base64 encoded.

Comment: File with same names can change, and should be re-uploaded.

Comment: The ETag algorithm isn't documented, though it is somewhat known.  For small files it's simply md5, but for larger files, [it's more complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186993/what-is-the-algorithm-to-compute-the-amazon-s3-etag-for-a-file-larger-than-5gb).  Could you be running into larger files?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but i have a it-works-for-me here:

```
% echo "hello world" > test.txt
% md5sum test.txt 
6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4  test.txt

% aws s3 cp test.txt s3://<bucket-name>/test.txt
upload: ./test.txt to s3://<bucket-name>/test.txt
% aws s3api head-object --bucket <bucket-name>  --key test.txt --query ETag --output text
"6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4"
```

Can you give more information about how you check the md5 on the python/bash part and how you query the ETag? Maybe there is a newline added somewhere or something like that