# How can I get the ETag / MD5 hash of a transcoded file back from AWS Elastic Transcoder?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm using Amazon Elastic Transcoder in conjunction with Lambda and Step Functions to transcode MP3s from WAV files.

I need to store the MD5 / S3 `ETag` header value of the transcoded MP3s in my database.

At the moment I'm having to fetch these using these in a separate process which is really slow:

```
s3_cli = boto3.client("s3",aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
s3_resp = s3_cli.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=mp3_key)
s3obj_etag = s3_resp['ETag'].replace('"', '')
```

Before putting this in place, I was hoping that Elastic Transcoder would provide the transcoded file(s) MD5 hash in the job response, but I can not see this anywhere.

Does anyone have any tips on how to approach this better or am I missing something in the response/docs?

Comment: Are you fetching the ETags by batch? Why don't you trigger a Lambda to do that for you when the S3 file is uploaded by Elastic Transcoder?

Comment: Yes, i'm already doing that via the separate process I describe above. It's just slow. I've also now encountered the issue where transcoder is delivering bigger files as multipart, so the etag doesn't match MD5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was hoping that Elastic Transcoder would provide the transcoded files ETag in the job response

**Unfortunately, it doesn't.**

As of the current AWS Python Boto3 1.18.60 SDK (or any other SDK including the REST API), the entity tag(s) for the output object(s) isn't returned anywhere in the [job response object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elastictranscoder.html#ElasticTranscoder.Client.read_job).

---

This is most likely because an entity tag represents a specific version of the object and is mostly used for efficient caching invalidation.

Elastic Transcoder jobs do not produce multiple *versions* of the same output and as such, why would it return the `ETag` value? If someone requires the ETag, they can get this from the S3 object.

Another question is what happens if there is multi-part output for large inputs? What does the SDK return? A *list* of `ETag` header values? You have multiple *parts*, but you don't have multiple *versions*.

This implementation would go against the [RFC 7232 specification for the `ETag` header](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7232#section-2.3):

> An entity-tag is an opaque **validator** for
> **differentiating between multiple representations of the same
> resource**, regardless of whether those multiple representations are
> due to resource state changes over time, content negotiation
> resulting in multiple representations being valid at the same time,
> or both.

---

Your actual problem, in this case, is that you want *the MD5 hash* of the file(s) even if they are multi-part.

Now your code will work for getting the MD5 hash for a single file, but if they are multi-part, they don't hash the multipart uploads as you would expect. Instead of calculating the hash of the entire file, Amazon calculates the hash of *each part* and then combines that into a single hash set as the `ETag` header.

This makes a lot of sense: they calculate the hashes of each part as they receive it. After all the parts have been transferred, they combine the hashes instead of trying to calculate a final MD5 hash by reading a file that could possibly be up to the AWS object size limit - *5 terabytes*. Try generating MD5 hashes for everyone's files when you're at Amazon's scale & you'll find that their way is quite clever :)

This is probably why the [S3 API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html) says the below:

> The ETag may or **may not be an MD5 digest** of the object data.

> **Objects created by** either the **Multipart Upload** or Part Copy operation **have ETags that are not MD5 digests**, regardless of the method of encryption.

It *is* an MD5 hash, but when it's a multi-part upload it *isn't* so the above is technically correct.

To calculate the MD5 hash correctly for multi-part uploads, try checking out this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19896823/4800344) in response to ["What is the algorithm to compute the Amazon-S3 Etag for a file larger than 5GB?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186993/what-is-the-algorithm-to-compute-the-amazon-s3-etag-for-a-file-larger-than-5gb).

---

To summarise, you, unfortunately, don't have the MD5 digest hash of the object(s) in the response back from Amazon Elastic Transcoder - you'll have to do this heavy lifting yourself & it can take long if you have huge files.

There's no workaround or quicker solution - you have the quickest solution as you're already getting the `ETag` value from the HEAD in the most efficient way.

I would perhaps recommend trying to parallelise the HTTP HEAD requests made to get the objects' metadata (`s3_cli.head_object(...)`) before trying to determine the final MD5 digest of the file(s).

That will definitely speed things up if you have 500 files for example - don't make the API requests separately.

You’ll definitely be able to send them in parallel, so offload the time you’d spend between requests all onto Amazon’s infrastructure.

Get the responses & then process together.